# Import Problem in magento 2.0.8

Tags: magento2, import

While I import a product using csv file, magento2 throw this error

```
Data validation is failed. Please fix errors and re-upload the file..
Following Error(s) has been occurred during importing process:
Only first 100 errors are displayed here. Download full report
1. Value for '%s' attribute contains incorrect value in rows: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
Checked rows: 10, checked entities: 10, invalid rows: 10, total errors: 10
```

Suggest me How to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I solved this problem

I created custom attribute with date format, I gave Date format is **DD/MM/YYYY, HH:MM**  But, Magento  2 use **MM/DD/YYYY,HH:MM**,  Miss matched Date format that's why this problem Ocuur.

Now Works for fine.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Coding problem may be caused .cvs file, I am using Araxis Merge v6.5 software will upload the files failed to open, the display as shown in the picture, and then delete the red part, then Save, and then upload no mistake！